# phonegap ios - jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

When i put script tag with jQuery in my page, the result of $('body') is empty array. And there are no errors in Safari console.
I tried to paste it in body, in head before and after cordova.js, tried to load it from CDN and to load local file, same result. 
On Android everything works fine.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="wApp">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 console.log("jQuery: ", jQuery, $);
 $(function() {
   console.log('Dom Ready');
   console.log('Body element: ', $('body'));
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 //// HTML content here
 //// Angular scripts here
</body>
</html>
```

Console result of this code, when is run it on emulator, is:

```
jQuery: function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
        }
Dom Ready
Body element: []
```

I tried to erase other scripts one by one, only jQuery script affects this behaviour. And only in iOS.

Comment: You have to wait for the cordova deviceready event. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova creates it own view, sort of like a web view, whenever you load the app, so it will not be created instantly. To solve this, cordova fires the `deviceready` event when the DOM has loaded. To get this, use `document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);`

So your script in your `<head>` tag should look something like this:

```
function deviceLoaded() {
    console.log("jQuery: ", jQuery, $);
    $(function() {
        console.log('Dom Ready');
        console.log('Body element: ', $('body'));
    });
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceLoaded, false);
```

Comment: [Vector Pointer to documentation on `deviceready`](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#004) event from [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: I forgot to tell it. I have a "deviceready" block of code, where i bind events to hardware buttons, so i know about deviceready, but thanks for a try. And if i move my example to this section, the result is the same. 
Also, in my example, "Dom ready" function fires, so the "body" tag must exists, no matter what ready state the device have